# Android ExtractEditText: Difficult for user to type, keyboard?

Tags: android, user-interface

When I run my Android program on the emulator or on my phone, it is impossible to type in the ExtractEditText because there is no keyboard and I cannot select the current editText because the cursor is on all three.
Here is the XML for my ExtractEditText if that helps:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Current Education"
    android:id="@+id/extractEditText16"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>
```

Here is a screenshot of not being able to select.
[Here is a screenshot of not being able to select.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bu7w.png)

Does anyone have a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible exactly what you want through Java.
    step 1: make all 3 EditText hide cursor.(you can remain one )
    step 2: in java file ,when touched the EditText, here you do. Make EditText show cursor.

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extractEditText16);
        editText1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText1.setCursorVisible(true);
                editText2.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText3.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText1.setHint("");  // just for understanding
                return false;
            }
        });
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extractEditText17);
        editText2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText2.setCursorVisible(true);
                editText1.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText3.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText2.setHint(""); // just for understanding
                return false;
            }
        });
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extractEditText18);
        editText3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText3.setCursorVisible(true);
                editText1.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText2.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText3.setHint("");   // just for understanding
                return false;
            }
        });

       <android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Current Education"
            android:id="@+id/extractEditText16"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

        <android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Current Education"
            android:id="@+id/extractEditText17"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>
        <android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Current Education"
            android:id="@+id/extractEditText18"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>
    </code>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the keyboard is still not showing up...How do I get it to show up?

Comment: I edited above code! your problem(not getting show up keyboard) there is no enough space for it. so remove margin_top="200" and so on..